# body-parser is not parsing json data

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

This is how I am using the package:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This is the body of my request:

```
{
    name: "jay",
    price: "12"
}
```

This is how I am extracting the body:

```
    const name = req.body.name;
    const price = req.body.price;
```

But both `name` and `price` returned `undefined`.

EDITED:

According to VS Code, this package is deprecated. But it should still work, no?

Comment: for deprecated problem, use`app.use(express.json())` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the request body should be JSON so property names should be in quote signs

```
{
    "name": "jay",
    "price": "12"
}
```